# Make REST Calls to Azure Devops

Tags: rest, authentication, azure-devops

I am trying to make REST calls to Azure DevOps (Build Pipeline) through my PAT and it works (c# and Postman).

But, I don't want to use my PAT anymore, so how can I know make REST calls from C# (and postman) without PAT and I don't want Interactive flow here every time (I can ok to obtain access token through interactive flow once) ?

Is it possible to make calls to Azure Devops through some access token (but how) or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) contains a list of all possible authentication mechanisms with appropriate samples. You can start from here and find the most relevant approach for your application.

Answer (score 0):

To change the method of authentication to Azure DevOps Services or Azure DevOps Server, change the VssCredential type passed to VssConnection when creating it.

**Visual Studio sign-in prompt (Microsoft Account or Azure Active Directory backed) for REST services (.NET Framework only)**

```
public static void MicrosoftAccountRestSample()
{
    // Create instance of VssConnection using Visual Studio sign-in prompt
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssClientCredentials());
}
```

**Azure Active Directory Authentication for REST services**

```
public static void AADRestSample()
{
    // Create instance of VssConnection using Azure AD Credentials for Azure AD backed account
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssAadCredential(userName, password));
}
```

**OAuth Authentication for REST services**

```
public static void OAuthSample()
{
    // Create instance of VssConnection using OAuth Access token
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(accessToken));
}
```

Comment: You are saying should I follow this page ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops

Comment: I have started following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops. But how to make REST calls after I get the repo info ?

Comment: I want to trigger pipeline runs REST (and that works with PAT). Would Vssconnection work ? I am triggering this REST Calls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0